# How to store countdown in local storage

Tags: javascript

```
function counter1() {

    var counter = 5;

    setInterval(function() {

        counter--;

        if (counter >= 0) {

            var id = document.getElementById("res");

            var bet = document.getElementById("pts");

            var on = document.getElementById("bet");

            var beth = document.getElementById("beth");

            var betv = document.getElementById("betv");

            id.innerHTML = "Results after&nbsp;" + counter + "&nbsp;seconds";

            beth.disabled = true;

            beth.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(229, 229, 229)";

            betv.disabled = true;

            betv.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(229, 229, 229)";

            beth.style.cursor = 'none';

            betv.style.cursor = 'none';

        }

        if (counter == 0) {

            counter2();

            var beth = document.getElementById("beth");

            var betv = document.getElementById("betv");

            beth.disabled = false;

            beth.style.backgroundColor = "#4CAF50";

            betv.disabled = false;

            betv.style.backgroundColor = "#008CBA";

            beth.style.cursor = 'pointer';

            betv.style.cursor = 'pointer';

            var random = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);

            var id1 = document.getElementById("res1");

            if (random < 50) {

                id1.innerHTML = "Heroes have won" + random;

            } else {

                id1.innerHTML = "Villains have won" + random;

            }

        }

    }, 1000);

}

function counter2() {

    var counter = 5;

    var on = document.getElementById("bet");

    setInterval(function() {

        counter--;

        if (counter == 9) {

            on.innerHTML = "";

        }

        if (counter >= 0) {

            id = document.getElementById("res");

            var bet = document.getElementById("pts");

            id.innerHTML = "Bet within&nbsp;" + counter + "&nbsp;seconds";

        }

        if (counter == 0) {

            counter1();

        }

    }, 1000);

}
```

I want this code to be stored in local storage ( countdown) ,,I want those countdown to be retrieved on page load, would appreciate if I could get some suggestions or if anyone could modify the code. is it possible to modify it from here to store countdown in local storage or should I recode from the beginning would appreciate on suggestions and ideas. Thank you!

Comment: Can you please remove the unnecessary white-space.

Comment: There's not a single reference of `localStorage` in your script -> What have you tried so far to solve this on your own?

Comment: You can use localstorage api , ref https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: . I don't have knowledge how to store it, I am here to get some suggestions on how to use it

Comment: Is there any video tutorial available I couldn't find a good one

Comment: The word countdown isn't even used in your code!

Comment: Yes I don't know how to implement on above code

Answer (score 0):

you can store value in local system.

to set the value of any variable then use

```
localStorage.setItem(key, value);
```

syntax to set a value in a local variable. here "key" means variable name and "value" means its value which you want to assign.

// to read data of local storage

```
let lastname = localStorage.getItem(key);
```

to get data of a variable you have to use above code. here in "key" means you have to provide variable name which you used at a time of assignment.

for more information please check out this link for more information
[click here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_localstorage.asp)